# What is the $$ function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What is the $$ function in JavaScript or what library does it come from?

Example code I have encountered:

```
$$('input_id')
```

I cannot locate any information regarding this function.

Comment: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/

Comment: I don't think this deserves a downvote so I'm evening it up.  If the OP doesn't know about Prototype he wouldn't know where $$ comes from.

Comment: Just me or Mootools also has a `$$` function.. Just saying. http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window:dollars

Comment: It's also something you can't google easily ... not sure if prototype is even the only or correct answer.

Comment: @kapep `$$` is a valid JS identifier. It can mean **anything**.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté What I meant is there are probably other (popular) frameworks that actually define it. Of course it could be anything, we won't know just from the code in the question.

Comment: @kapep Yes, what I meant is that as it is a valid identifier, this question may be too localized as when new libraries are created (letting alone current lesser know libraries) this question and answers will be obsolete either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in Chrome, it provides `$$` in the console by default as a wrapper around doing

```
document.querySelectorAll(...)
```

`$$` on it's own however is not any special value, it entirely depends on the system running the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Matt Ball posted the answer in his comment, but here is a bit more detail.

Most likely the code you're referencing is making use of the [$$](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) function provided by the [Prototype JavaScript library](http://prototypejs.org/).  Prototype.js is a JavaScript library similar to jQuery and it provides many similar functions to interact with the DOM, perform AJAX requests, and more.

Answer (score 0):

The `$$` function could be any function. It's a valid name and the only correct way to determine what `$$` is from, is to find where it's set in the JavaScript code.

That said, [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) and [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) are common libraries which use the `$$` variable for utility functions.

One way to *find* what's setting the `$$` function is to use the debugging console (<kbd>F12</kbd> in most browsers) to print out `$$.toString()`. This will produce the function body, which can be used to determine where the function was set.

Additionally, if the body is something along the lines of:

```
function () {
    [native code]
}
```

Then you're probably looking at a function which was implemented by the browser.